# Scheduler Current Tasks - Is 92 too high?

Tags: azure-sql-database

When I run the following query on my Azure SQL database:

```
SELECT 
    scheduler_id,
    cpu_id,
    current_tasks_count,    
    work_queue_count,       
    runnable_tasks_count,           
    pending_disk_io_count   
FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE scheduler_id < 255 OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

I am currently seeing values of 0, 0, 92, 0, 0, 0.

My performance tier is currently S1 (20 DTUs). I have been under 30% DTU utilization the entire day. Yet, in spite of this, 92 tasks seems like an awful lot of tasks waiting to be executed or executing. Also, 92 for current tasks isn't a one-time reading. I have been seeing this value (between 90 and 95) for the past half-hour. My current DTU percentage is about 15% (with 92 current tasks).

Comment: What problem are you having? Read the example at the bottom of this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-schedulers-transact-sql

Comment: While sys.dm_os_schedulers can help see how many schedulers you have for your database - for DTU measurement, recommend you use other methods. For example, if you see a degradation in overall performance, monitor the sys.dm_db_resource_stats and sys.resource_stats dynamic management views in order to understand CPU, I/O and memory consumption.